# Можно ли под Linux на Python читать последовательный порт только когда в нем есть сообщение?

Tags: python, linux, события, serial

Есть устройство, подключенный к компютеру через USB интерфейс, который распознается как USB устройство: /dev/ttyUSB0. Есть ли способ постоянно не читать порт в цикле, а как-то настроить событие, которое произойдет, когда входящий буфер наполнен?
ОС - Debian,
язык - Python.

Comment: [select в python](http://www.py-my.ru/post/4bfb3c691d41c846bc00006a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это средство называется *select()*.

1. Открываете файл /dev/ttyUSB0
2. Готовите вызов *select()*. Это довольно сложный процесс, я не буду вдаваться в подробности
3. Запускаете нить (!!!) чтения устройства.
4. Внутри нити вызываете *select()*. Нить повисает на ожидании ввода
5. Основная программа занимается своими делами
6. Буфер ввода устройства заполнен. Драйвер информирует об этом ОС
7. ОС снимает Вашу нить ввода с ожидания, *select()* завершается и нить начинает обработку введённого буфера.
8. По окончанию обработки нить опять повисает на *select()*
9. Основная программа возобновляет нормальную работу.

За подробностями, рекомендую:

Стивенс Р., Раго С.
UNIX. Профессиональное программирование, 2-е издание.

Раздел 14.5.1.

Answer (score 1):

На последовательных портах обычно не так много данных, чтоб выбирать полными буферами.
Я предлагаю не заморачиваться на `select`.

[Самая распространенная библиотека уже использует select](https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/blob/92d101613be41ecb2f2054c3f43a006fbe6f9966/serial/serialposix.py#L483)

Для python-3/asyncio:
pyserial-asyncio - читаете в основном цикле, как полная строка набирается - вызываете callback.

На втором питоне запускать отдельный тред. Сделать буфер, наполнять и слать сигнал. Тоже, что и с select, только без него.